# debugfs occasionally fails to read inode data

Tags: ext4, inode, debugfs

I need to get date and time when a file was created. The file is stored at ext4 filesystem so the information is available in the i-node and I use debugfs to read this information:

```
# debugfs -R "stat <3922>" /dev/sda1 | grep crtime
debugfs 1.43-WIP (18-May-2015)
crtime: 0x5b646acd:b0175ac8 -- Fri Aug  3 14:46:37 2018
```

That works fine but the command sometimes fails:

```
# debugfs -R "stat <3922>" /dev/sda1
debugfs 1.43-WIP (18-May-2015)
/dev/sda1: Block bitmap checksum does not match bitmap while reading block bitmap
stat: Filesystem not open
```

The next debugfs execution returns correct data.

What does exactly mean the error `Block bitmap checksum does not match bitmap while reading block bitmap` ?

Comment: Modern versions of the `stat` utility (from coreutils) will show you the birth time, too.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Unfortunately it is an embedded linux, that is not easy to upgrade.

Comment: Do you have a C compiler? https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/statx/test-statx.c will do almost the same thing as the `stat` utility.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: I have a C compiler but statx is not an option because it was added to the linux kernel 4.11 and I have 3.10.

Comment: If your filesystem sits on top of an lvm volume, you could try making a snapshot and then run debugfs on the snapshot. That should reduce, but not eliminate, inconsistencies caused by examining a constantly changing filesystem.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Good hint. Nevertheless it is not an LVM based filesystem. I did a workaround to run debugfs in a loop till it returns correct data but still want to know what is the error cause.